What function describes the Recaman Sequence?
For those of you who don't know, the Recaman sequence starts at 0. To generate the next term of the sequence, you count the number of terms in the sequence that came before it, and then add or subtract that number. If the term subtracted would be both positive and appeared nowhere in the sequence yet, then you subtract, otherwise you add. So the first few terms of the Recaman sequence are: 0, 1, 3, 6, 2, 7, 13, 20, 12, 21, 11, 22, 10, 23, 9, 24, 8, 25, 43, 62 and so on. There's also a helpful Numberphile video on the Recaman Sequence: The Slightly Spooky Recaman Sequence - Numberphile
This function, we'll call Recaman(n), finds the nth term of the Recaman Sequence. Of course, you could simply apply this process until you reach the desired term, but is there a more efficient method out there for finding these terms?

See https://oeis.org/A005132
